# Canvasjs chart works in jsfiddle.net but not on my node.js environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, canvasjs

My aim is to create chart and am using Canvasjs. The code am testing works well on jsfiddle.net but won't work on my node.js setup. I am so confuse and I have tried to fix it, but cannot. Please help. Thanks. See my code below:

**index.js**

```
   router.get('/seare', function(req, res, next){
      res.render('seare');

      });
```

**seare.ejs**

```html
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var dataPoints = [];
    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/45rin", function(result) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= result.dataPoints.length - 1; i++) {
        dataPoints.push({
          label: result.dataPoints[i].label,
          y: parseInt(result.dataPoints[i].y)
        });
      }

      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        data: [{
          type: "column",
          dataPoints: dataPoints
        }]
      });

      chart.render();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you certain `seare.ejs` is in the same folder as `index.js`? I'm suggesting the path to seare could be incorrect in your call to `res.render('seare')`

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am 100% sure. I even test it by displaying text and it shows. It works with just viewing html file, but doesn't work through express route. Am using Visual Studio Code.                   `// view engine setup:
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

Comment: Anything in the dev tools console?